# python capture URLError code

Tags: python

I want to use Python to monitor a website that uses HTTPS.
The problem is that the certificate on the website is invalid.
I don't care about that, I just want to know that the website is running.

My working code looks like this:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
req = Request("https://somedomain.com")

try:
    response = urlopen(req)
except HTTPError as e:
    print('server couldn\'t fulfill the request')
    print('error code: ', e.code)
except URLError as e:
        print(e.args)       
else:
    print ('website ok')
```

that ends in URLError being called. The error code is 645.

```
C:\python>python monitor443.py
(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)'),)
```

So, I'm trying to except code 645 as OK. I've tried this:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
req = Request("https://somedomain.com")

try:
    response = urlopen(req)
except HTTPError as e:
    print('server couldn\'t fulfill the request')
    print('error code: ', e.code)
except URLError as e:
        if e.code == 645:
            print("ok")
        print(e.args)       
else:
    print ('website ok')
```

but get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "monitor443.py", line 11, in <module>
    if e.code == 645:
AttributeError: 'URLError' object has no attribute 'code'
```

how do I add this exception?

Comment: [`URLError` is a subclass of OSError](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38773209/344286) might it be found in [`e.errno`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError.errno)?

Comment: e.errno returns "none"

Comment: Also... 645 isn't the errorno, that's the line of C source that the error occurred on, AFAIK.

Comment: Can you not just catch the [SSLError](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLError)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the great `requests` package. It will simplify your life when doing http communication. See http://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/.

```
pip install requests
```

To skip certificate check, you would do something like this (note the `verify` parameter!):

```
requests.get('https://kennethreitz.com', verify=False)
<Response [200]>
```

See the full documentation [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/).

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't install the SLL library (egg_info error).
This is what I ended up doing

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError

def sendEmail(r):    
    #send notification
    print('send notify')

req = Request("https://somedomain.com")

try:
    response = urlopen(req)
except HTTPError as e:
    print('server couldn\'t fulfill the request')
    print('error code: ', e.code)
    sendEmail('server couldn\'t fulfill the request')
except URLError as e:
        theReason=str(e.reason)
        #[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)
        if theReason.find('CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED') == -1:
            sendEmail(theReason)
        else:
            print('website ok')         
else:
    print('website ok')
```